# Js canvas context gives undefined in object

Tags: javascript, html

So... I have this code here. It is meant to get the context of a canvas:

```
let room ={
    canvas: document.getElementById("room"),
    ctx: this.canvas.getContext("2d")
}
```

but it gives me this error: Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'canvas'). Why?

Comment: `let room = {canvas: document.getElementById('room')}; room.ctx = room.canvas.getContext('2d');`. `this` does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: because `this` is probably referring to the window object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Define The Canvas First

```
let cvs = document.getElementById("room");
let room = {
    ctx: cvs.getContext("2d")
}
```